# animate two views smoothly in parallel in android

Tags: android, animation, view

Is there a way to animate two different views parallel smoothly. I am able to perform the animation by calling `startAnimation` on both views separately, but then the animation does not happen smoothly.

Comment: Have you tried using `Threads`?

Comment: try to use AnimationSet. i think this will help you.